# why does wagtail keyword is appended to my newly created app name?

Tags: django, wagtail

I am new to wagtail cms and i am trying to create my first app (named blog) according to official documentation.

My problem is that when i run the `python manage.py makemigrations` command, it says that `No module named 'blog.apps.BlogConfigwagtail'`

wagtail keyword is appended to my app name and django can't find my app.

Comment: Post your `settings.py` and your project structure.

Comment: @DanSwain I have just downloaded wagtail and have not changed anything.

Comment: A few things to try:  Make sure `blog` is in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.  Specify the name of the app after the `makemigrations` command:  `python manage.py makemigrations blog`.  In the `blog` app folder, create a "migrations" folder if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Also, make sure you've remembered the comma `,` character after the entry you added to INSTALLED_APPS - if you leave it out, it will get joined to the string after it.

Comment: @gasman it was the problem. the comma was missed! thx ;)